# ImportError raised when trying to load 'bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3': cannot import name 'flatatt'

Tags: django, heroku, django-bootstrap3

I create a project use django, and the upload it to heroku.

It can run successfully in local environment, and functions can also work well. I upload successfully without any problems, but when I visit it in heroku(https://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/), it have some issues like this:

```
InvalidTemplateLibrary at /

Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3': cannot import name 'flatatt'

Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
https://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com/
Django Version:
2.0.2
Exception Type:
InvalidTemplateLibrary
Exception Value:
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'bootstrap3.templatetags.bootstrap3': cannot import name 'flatatt'
Exception Location:
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py in get_package_libraries, line 125
Python Executable:
/app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:
3.6.4
Python Path:
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:
Sun, 25 Feb 2018 02:19:09 +0000
```

I tried to use django-bootstrap4, but it also have deployment problems with django-bootstrap3.

How can I do?

Thanks a lot.

---

update:

- requirements.txt

  pip freeze > requirements.txt

The requirements.txt contents like this:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Blockquote
django==2.0.2
-e git+https://git.heroku.com/APP_NAME.git@cbb5b522d**SECRET**710#egg=django_bootstrap3
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pytz==2017.3
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

NOTICE:
That is the originial file.I modified the 4th line to  a certain version,like `django-bootstrap3==6.2.2`.

- bootstrap3 settings

Some settings to reference in my virtual-environment:

`ll_env/Lib/site-packages/bootstrap3/bootstrap.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from importlib import import_module
...
```

`ll_env/Lib/site-packages/bootstrap3/utils.py`

```
from django.forms.utils import flatatt
from django.template import Variable, VariableDoesNotExist
from django.template.base import FilterExpression, kwarg_re, TemplateSyntaxError
from django.template.loader import get_template
...
```

Comment: What does you `requirements.txt` contain? Does that match the output when you do `pip freeze` in your local environment?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I have updated my question.

Comment: You haven’t added any new information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. let `requestments.txt` to be an empty file;
2. pull to heroku : `git push heroku master`;
3. fill `requestments.txt` file with privious contents, like:

   ```
   dj-database-url==0.4.2
   django==2.0.2
   django-bootstrap3
   gunicorn==19.7.1
   psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
   pytz==2017.3
   whitenoise==3.3.1
   ```
4. push to heroku again : `git push heroku master`